# Conversion of NSString to NSDate failing

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have the following piece of code..

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm"];
NSString *dateString = @"10/27/2012 18:00";
NSDate *parsedDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString] ;
NSLog(@"Parsed Date.. %@",[parsedDate description]);
```

I am getting the NSLog statement as `Parsed Date.. 2011-12-25 00:00:00 +0000`. I would appreciate any help in resolving this. I just want to convert that NSString to its NSDate equivalent. Tried using NSTimeZone as well, but no effect. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use *lower case year* indication, `yyyy` instead of `YYYY`:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"];
```

If you want to get the timezone right you need to set the timezone of the `NSDateFormatter`. By default it uses the timezone of your device. For the time at GMT use the following.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"];
NSString *dateString = @"10/27/2012 18:00";
NSDate *parsedDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString] ;
NSLog(@"Parsed Date.. %@",[parsedDate description]);
```

Comment: You should accept this answer he solved your problem.  Look at the docs for timezone formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an incorrect format string. See [the documentation](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns). Basically, capital `YYYY` is "week of year year". Try to use lowercase `yyyy` instead, i.e.

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"];
```

Comment: Nice. That works for the date just fine, but for the time I am getting **Parsed Date.. 2012-10-27 12:30:00 +0000** Should I use a timezone format? or can i do it without that as well?