# NSDate and dateString in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdata

I want to save a date object to the backend of my App. This is the code:

```
NSDate *date = self.birthPickerView.date;
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@", stringFromDate);

NSDate *endDate = [formatter dateFromString:stringFromDate];
[formatter release];

NSLog(@"%@", endDate);

// Save to database
[user setObject:endDate forKey:@"birth"];
```

This is the print out result:

```
1985-03-05 00:00:00
1985-03-04 23:00:00 +0000
```

The end date is not right. I want to save `1985-03-05` in the database. Can you help me what is wrong?

**Edit**

```
[self.birthPickerView setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

        NSLog(@"%@", self.birthPickerView.date);
        NSLog(@"%@", self.birthPickerView.timeZone);

        [user setObject:self.birthPickerView.date forKey:self.navTitle];
```

This code save `1984-03-04 23:00:00` in database. what is wrong with it?

Comment: will this same issue appears if you use a different formatter the second time? ie a formatter without HH:mm:ss

Comment: dont make it into a string to store it in the DB.. that WRONG in ay case

Comment: @xCode, Yes the same happens.

Comment: You should use lowercase yyyy.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989509/conversion-of-nsstring-to-nsdate-failing (and many others).

Comment: @AnnaKarenina, the problem is not the year. When I save the data in database it is : 1985-03-04 23:00:00, but is should be 1985-03-05 00:00:00.

Comment: Yes, it's unrelated to the time zone issue but YYYY will give the wrong year when the date is in the first week of January.

Comment: Somehow you've got a different timezone set in your date picker vs your date formatter.  (Or, perhaps, you're using an interface to store the date in your database that is referencing a different timezone.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why would you need to convert your date into a string, and then back into the date again.

However, I'm pretty sure this happens because you didn't set the timezone on your NSDateFormatter. The default time zone is GMT which might cause the time offset you see there.

Comment: You are completely right. I just wanted to show the print out.

Comment: Still I couldn't fix it. how can I set time zone for date picker?

Comment: UIDatePicker has a timeZone property, try setting it there. Also, don't forget to use the timeZone property of NSDateFormatter as well if you are printing the result. If I remember correctly, NSDate is not aware of time zone concepts.

Comment: I set the timezone like this :  `[self.birthPickerView setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];`but it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, actually, the default formatter timezone is the current local timezone.  You have to explicitly set the timezone to get GMT.

Comment: @Ali -- You have to set the date formatter timezone as well.  Or let both default to local time.

Comment: @Hot Licks, that's what I do, but still it save wrong date in database. check what I added to end of my question.

Comment: @Ali - You don't say how you're updating the database.  The problem could be there.